# Чтение писем из gmail: Invalid credentials (Failure)

Tags: python, gmail, imap

На python пытаюсь прочитать почту gmail:

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
mail.login('mail', 'pass')
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox")
```

Выпадает ошибка:

```
  messages,unseen = gmail_checker('mail','pass')
File "mail_listener.py", line 18, in gmail_checker
  i.login(username,password)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imaplib.py", line 582, in login
  raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)'
```

В настройках включил доступ по Imap: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: другие клиенты позволяют по этому имени, паролю по imap почту смотреть?

Comment: @jfs а я других и не знаю.

Comment: на телефоне почту смотрите? (e.g., Apple Mail) На настольном клиенте? (таком как Mozilla Thunderbird)

Comment: @jfs на аднроиде приложение gmail есть. Работает

Comment: вы уверены что оно именно по imap работает, а не по своему API? Так как [код должен и так работать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22159037/4279), поэтому проблема вероятно именно с настройками учётной записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы защитить ваш аккаунт, начиная с 30 мая 2022 года Google больше не поддерживает сторонние приложения и устройства, которые предлагают войти в аккаунт Google только с помощью имени пользователя и пароля.

Важно! Для клиентов Google Workspace и Google Cloud Identity дата прекращения поддержки будет другой. Мы объявим ее позже в блоге Workspace.

Дополнительная информация приводится ниже.

Google может блокировать любые попытки входа в ваш аккаунт на сайтах или в приложениях, которые не соответствуют нашим стандартам безопасности. Мы соблюдаем такие меры предосторожности, чтобы защитить ваши данные от хакеров.

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо включить доступ небезопасным приложениям по ссылке https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps